# Is there any openerp module that would do this?

Tags: odoo

I have the following problem:

I have different products but they all have the same price, and itś supposed that if you buy five of these products (these five could be different, but of the same price) you get a special discount at the moment of making the invoice.

My question:

is there already a module that would do this??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no public module which do that. This will change the way the product price is calculated on OpenERP.